# Fast expansion of large expressions

Tags: series-expansion

I want to expand a very huge expression. Is there any way to do that without Series? Series works very slow, even when I want to find

```
Series[expression,{x,0,0}]
```

I can not put x=0 and find the value of the expression because there are some terms like below in the expression:

...+ f/x-f/x +...

I also can not also use Simplify or Limit, because it is large and MM can not simplify it.

Can anyone help me please?

a simple example could be:

a^2/x+ x/b+ c x^2/+ g x^10/Sqrt[x^2+v^2] - a^2/x +...

Comment: Perhaps `Limit[expr,x->0] could help? What means `f1/(x)-f1/(x)`?

Comment: It is also very difficult for MM @UlrichNeumann

Comment: I have edited f1... @UlrichNeumann

Comment: Mathematica evaluates `f/x - f/x (* 0*)`, so you probably mean somthing like a singularity ?  Perhaps you can provide a simplified example of your problem?

Comment: Yes. It is why I can not put x=0 and find what I am seeking for. @UlrichNeumann

Comment: I have added a toy example @UlrichNeumann

Comment: Thanks. It looks like you already have the expansion you are looking for. In your examlpe (Laurent series) also negative powers of x are involved. The is Indeterminate for `x=0`

Comment: No I don't. look at sqrt please @UlrichNeumann

Comment: Your example gives `Series[a^2/x + x/b + c x^2/+g x^10/Sqrt[x^2 + v^2] - a^2/x, {x, 0,12}] (*SeriesData[x, 0, { b^(-1), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, c g^(-1) (v^2)^Rational[-1, 2]}, 1, 13, 1]*)` without any problems `x->0`

Comment: it is only an example. As I have described in the question, the real expression is very huge and I can not use Series for real expression. @UlrichNeumann

Comment: If only specific terms in `x` are desired, possibly `Coefficient` or `SeriesCoefficient` will do better that `Expand` or `Series`.

Answer (score 3):

First, let us generate a large sum with terms similar to your mini-example.

```
hugeExpr[n_] := 
  Plus @@ Array[
    RandomInteger[{-10, 10}] x^
       RandomInteger[{-3, 1000}] Sqrt[x + RandomInteger[{-10, 10}]]^
       RandomInteger[{-1, 1}] &, n];

expression = hugeExpr[300000];
```

The actual number of addends (`Length[expression]`) might not be 300K, but it will still be a large count. Now, the answer to your problem.

```
ParallelMap[Series[#, {x, 0, 2}] &, expression, Method -> "ItemsPerEvaluation" -> 15]
```

I tried it on a expression with over 40K terms and it took less than 2 seconds. If your expression is orders of magnitude larger than that, I would suggest you split it in chunks of say 100K addends, use `ParallelMap` on each chunk separately, save those results to individual files, and add them up later.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer. When I try below code, MM still do not return anything:                             exp1 = f2x (-M11xx + M12xx);
exp11 = ParallelMap[Series[#, {al, 0, 2}] &, exp1, 
    Method -> "ItemsPerEvaluation" -> 15] // Normal;

Comment: exp1 is here: https://pastebin.com/RjJtAALb

Comment: Is it possible to use the same method of parallel computing for SeriesCoefficient?